# How to redirect using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need my site to redirect from this url:

```
mysite.com/old/dir/param1/param2/...
```

to

```
mysite.com/dir/param1/param2/...
```

I need to keep the params, just remove the "old" in the url.

How can I add this rule to my .htaccess?

Thanks!!!

Here's my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^old/dir/(.*) mysite.com/dir/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right rule for it was

and I had to place it before all the other rules. So my .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^old/dir/(.*) /dir/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just write it like this.

```
Rediret 301 mysite.com/old/dir/param1/param2/(.*) mysite.com/dir/param1/param2/$1
```

If you're planning to redirect the entire directory of `old/dir` to `dir/`, then try this:

```
Redirect 301 mysite.com/old/dir/(.*) mysite.com/dir/$1
```

The next option you could try is, Url Rewriting.

Assuming that you have set your Rewrite Engine on and have set the Rewrite Base, add these lines:

```
RewriteRule ^old/dir/(.*) mysite.com/dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Redirect 301 mysite.com/old/dir/(.*) mysite.com/dir/$1 returns in a "Internal Server Error". It is not redirecting

Comment: Is the Rewrite Engine on and have you set the base url?

Comment: check out my post, I just added my .htaccess content!

Comment: Okay. Just add one more line may be after Rewrite Engine. RewriteBase /

Comment: :( blank page. Nothing changed!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17887/discussion-between-rocky-and-content01)